Function is constant on the solution of ODE proof verification
Let $\Omega\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ open, $f:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ continuous, $V:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be $C^1$, then the following conditions are equivalent

$\forall x(t)\in\Omega$ solutions to the equation $x'(t)=f(x(t),t)$ the function $t \mapsto V(x(t),t)$ is constant
$\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}(x,t)+\nabla_x V(x,t) \cdot f(x,t)=0,\; \forall (x,t)\in\Omega$

Using chainrule for derivative of V we get
$$\frac{d}{dt}V(x(t),t)=\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}(x(t),t)+\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\partial V}{\partial x_i} \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial t}(x(t),t)=\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}(x(t),t)+\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\partial V}{\partial x_i}f_i(x(t),t)=$$$$=\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}(x(t),t)+\nabla_x V(x(t),t)\cdot f(x(t),t)$$
$2. \implies 1.$ Let $x(t)\in\Omega, x:I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a solution to $x'=f(x,t)$, then by the equalities above we can see that $V(x(t),t)$ is constant .
$1. \implies 2.$ Let $(x_0,t_0)\in\Omega$, then by the Peano theorem $\exists\delta >0$ and solution $x:(t_0-\delta,t_0+\delta)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $x'=f(x,t)$ satisfying the initial condition $x(t_0)=x_0$. Then we have
$$0=\frac{d}{dt}V(x(t),t)=\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}(x(t),t)+\nabla_x V(x(t),t)\cdot f(x(t),t)$$
and plugging $t:=t_0$ yields
$$0=\frac{d}{dt}V(x_0,t_0)=\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}(x_0,t_0)+\nabla_x V(x_0,t_0)\cdot f(x_0,t_0),\forall(x_0,t_0)\in\Omega$$
I'm not sure if $1. \implies 2.$ is correct
